# Unable to connect to MongoDB container from .NET Core WebAPI container, but can connect normally

Tags: c#, mongodb, docker, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to connect to a MongoDB container using a .NET core 3.1 webapi container but every time I build and run the webapi container I get the following exception thrown in one of the services when its attempting to get data using C# MongoDB.Driver from the mongo container:

```
'A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "Automatic", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/localhost:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/localhost:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
 ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (10061): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. [::1]:27017
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(Exception source)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<>c.<ConnectAsync>b__274_0(IAsyncResult iar)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.ConnectAsync(Socket socket, EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.CreateStreamAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.HeartbeatAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2020-06-07T05:10:17.3502634Z" }] }.'
```

I can successfully connect to the MongoDB container using MongoDB compass or even using the same web api IIS express instace, the above exception is only thrown when I try to connect using a docker container. I inspected both containers and confirmed that they are both running on the same network.

Here the Dockerfile for the webapi:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-nanoserver-1903 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-nanoserver-1903 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["API/API.csproj", "API/"]
RUN dotnet restore "API/API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/API"
RUN dotnet build "API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "API.dll"]
```

MongoDB container is using the latest official MongoDb image. The docker image is run using the following command :

```
docker run -d -p 27017-27019:27017-27019 --name mongodb mongo:latest
```

The webapi appsettings.json looks like this:

```
{
  "DatabaseSettings": {
    "CollectionName": "collectionName",
    "ConnectionString": "mongodb://host.docker.internal:27017",
    "DatabaseName": "db"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

The .NET core 3.1 webapi was built following [Microsofts tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

For further information here is what the Startup.cs file looks like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // requires using Microsoft.Extensions.Options
    services.Configure<DatabaseSettings>(
        Configuration.GetSection(nameof(DatabaseSettings)));

    services.AddSingleton<IDatabaseSettings>(sp =>
        sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<DatabaseSettings>>().Value);

    services.AddSingleton<EarningsService>();

    services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader();
    }));

    services.AddControllers();
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    //app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

I've looked at all of the following questions to try and figure out how to connect:

- [Connecting to Mongodb docker container from another docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52417322/connecting-to-mongodb-docker-container-from-another-docker-container)
- [Nodejs application docker unable to connect to mongodb docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53922856/nodejs-application-docker-unable-to-connect-to-mongodb-docker-container)
- [Unable to connect to mongoDB running in docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828021/unable-to-connect-to-mongodb-running-in-docker-container)
- [How to connect to MongoDB running in Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644465/how-to-connect-to-mongodb-running-in-docker-container)
- https://success.docker.com/article/how-can-i-access-mongodb-container-from-another-container

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please check whether both of the container are in same docker network?
you can inspect docker network ip using docker inspect command.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62229008/how-to-allow-all-hosts-to-a-replica-set-in-mongodb/62233373#62233373 use non-loopback addresses

Comment: @TayburRahaman I already state in the question that both containers are on the same docker network.

Comment: @D.SM can you elaborate as to how to use non-loop back ids? I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: The linked answer describes what to do.

Comment: The issue was that the I wasn't updating the appsettings.Development.json, it was using localhost instead of docker.host.internal, once I updated that file to match with the appsettings.json file everything worked. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

First of all the containers has to be on the same network and you need to specify the mongodb container's connection string something like this

WINDOWS:
*"ConnectionString": "mongodb://:@host.docker.internal:27017/db-name?directConnection=true".*

MAC OS:
*"ConnectionString": "mongodb://:@docker.for.mac.localhost:27017/db-name?directConnection=true".*